# what's the meaning of dataport -1 in flink web UI

Tags: apache-flink

could you tell me

what's the meaning of **dataport  -1** in flink web UI?

flink web ui screenshot:

[image: flink web ui screenshot]

method to replicate this:

run flink shell local mode

and execute official example:

```
val dataStream = senv.fromElements(1, 2, 3, 4)
dataStream.countWindowAll(2).sum(0).print()    
val streamTable = stenv.fromDataStream(dataStream, 'num)    
val resultTable = streamTable.select('num).where('num % 2 === 1 )    
resultTable.toAppendStream[Row].print()    
senv.execute("My streaming program")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Port is the port at which Taskmanager receives data transfer requests for example for shuffles.

When it's set to -1 this means that this is local execution i.e. there will be no communication via the network, thus InetSocketAddress will not be created and netty will not listen on data port.